# How do I hide tabs or TabsAdapter using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: tabs, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

How do I hide tabs dynamically? I'm using ActionBarShelock to make swipe tabs and SearchView. When I show the search results in a listview I want to hide the whole row of tabs. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to hide tabs, you can call:

```
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

when you're done you can go back to tabs mode:

```
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Comment: I don't know why this hasn't been accepted but it works perfectly.  Thanks.